# Pandas dataframe: writing specific values to a file with specific formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, dataframe, file-io

I want to update external files.  I want to do this by writing new data from Pandas dataframes to the files in a particular format.

Here is an example of the first two blocks of data in a file (what I want my new data from the dataframes to look like when I write the data to the files).  "`identifieri`" is a unique name for a block of data and dataframe.

```
(Lines of comments, then)
identifier1       label2 = i \ label3        label4                                  
label5
A1 = -5563.88 B2 = -4998 C3 = -203.8888 D4 = 5926.8 
E5 = 24.99876 F6 = 100.6666 G7 = 30.008 H8 = 10.9999
J9 = 1000000 K10 = 1.0002 L11 = 0.1
M12

identifier2       label2 = i \ label3        label4                                  
label5
A1 = -788 B2 = -6554 C3 = -100.23 D4 = 7526.8 
E5 = 20.99876 F6 = 10.6666 G7 = 20.098 H8 = 10.9999
J9 = 1000000 K10 = 1.0002 L11 = 0.000
M12
...
```

In the dataframes, the new data are in two columns called `Labels` and `Numbers`. Each label goes with one number.  For example, there are labels `A1`, `B2`, `C3`, etc (see the example above) and for the "identifier2 data block, the corresponding numbers are `-788`, `-6554`, `-100.23`. However, there are also other data that I don't need.  I only need data from specific rows.

So far I have tried to get the specific labels and numbers I need from a dataframe and then write them in append mode to a file.  I can print one label and its number from a dataframe:

```
df.set_index("Labels", inplace=True)
print("Label 1", df.loc["label1", 'Numbers'])
```

My plan is to get each label and number I need and then append them to a file along with appropriate spaces.  However, when I try this:

```
df.loc["label1", 'Numbers'].to_csv('file.txt', mode='a', index = False, sep=' ')
```

I get: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_csv'`

It seems like my method is clunky and it will be hard to figure out how to add spaces and newlines.  If anyone knows of a more foolproof and sophisticated method, I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't even bother using the built-in utilities since this is kind of an unusual output, and its only a couple lines to iterate through the `DataFrame` anyway, and gives you alot of control over the final output.

1. Create a `str` and add any headers, opening comments, etc
2. Cycle through each identifier
3. Grab each value from the `DataFrame` and put it into the output `str`
4. Add newlines as appropriate to make it look like the target format

Here is a runnable code that shows how you might accomplish that (the field block with `rng` and `dfs` are just there to generate some sample data and can be ignore for your purposes). Feel free to comment with any follow up questions, or if I got the formats wrong let me know and I'll adjust.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

# Generate some random data that matches the description
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
dfs = {
    idname: pd.DataFrame(data=[
        {
            'Labels': string.ascii_uppercase[i] + str(i + 1),
            'Numbers': rng.integers(0, 1000)
        } for i in range(20)
    ]) for idname in ['identifier1', 'identifier2', 'identifier3']
}

# Make this list whatever output fields you want in the file
desired_fields = [string.ascii_uppercase[i] + str(i + 1) for i in range(11)]
# Seems like data is put into the file in groups of 4
stride = 4
# This the final string to be written to file
outstr = ''
# Add "Lines of comments"
outstr += '// comment1\n// comment2\n// comment3\n// comment4\n'
for idname, id_data in dfs.items():
    # Append the header like region
    outstr += f'{idname}       label2 = i \ label3        label4\nlabel5\n'
    # Append the "field = #" region
    for i, field in enumerate(desired_fields):
        # Grab the value from the Numbers field for the row in this
        #   DataFrame that matches that Labels value
        try:
            value = str(id_data.loc[id_data['Labels'] == field].iloc[0]['Numbers'])
        except IndexError:
            # Handle missing data here
            value = 'N/A'

        # Format that name value pair, can easily be adjusted
        outstr += f'{field} = {value} '
        # If a newline is necessary, append it based on stride
        if i % stride == stride - 1:
            outstr += '\n'
    # If the stride leaves us without a newline, add one
    if not outstr[-1] == '\n':
        outstr += '\n'
    # Add a blank space between identifiers
    outstr += '\n'

# Write to file or print or whatever
print(outstr)
with open('outputfile.txt', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write(outstr)
```

Here is the output I get, which looks pretty similar to your example data:

```
// comment1
// comment2
// comment3
// comment4
identifier1       label2 = i \ label3        label4
label5
A1 = 89 B2 = 773 C3 = 654 D4 = 438 
E5 = 433 F6 = 858 G7 = 85 H8 = 697 
I9 = 201 J10 = 94 K11 = 526 

identifier2       label2 = i \ label3        label4
label5
A1 = 500 B2 = 370 C3 = 182 D4 = 926 
E5 = 781 F6 = 643 G7 = 402 H8 = 822 
I9 = 545 J10 = 443 K11 = 450 

identifier3       label2 = i \ label3        label4
label5
A1 = 165 B2 = 758 C3 = 700 D4 = 354 
E5 = 67 F6 = 970 G7 = 445 H8 = 893 
I9 = 677 J10 = 778 K11 = 759
```

Comment: thank you so much for the clear explanation.  I'm working through some errors.  The lines aren't always four numbers long so I'm working on figuring out how to generalize that part.

Comment: @Ant If you need any additional help with that, feel free to ask.

Comment: thank you much.  I will do my best first but may ask later if you have time.

Comment: really appreciate this.  I have learned a lot.